# Software for solving symbolic matrix expressions

Tags: math-software, programming, symbolic-computation

I've seen that there are multiple softwares to solve equations like sageMath, sympy, maxima... All of these seem to work great for scalars but I haven't found any software which can solve symbolic linear algebra expressions like $$\begin{aligned}\text{solve } Xb&=y \text{ for b} \\ \Leftrightarrow b &= X^{-1}y\end{aligned}$$ symbolically, it only works if you provide the elements of the matrices. Is there a software that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mean a quick google shows sympy works: https://paulpotgieter.org/2020/10/30/solving-symbolic-matrix-equations-in-python-with-sympy/

Also Matlab supports this too natively

Comment: thanks I must've missed that site, thats all I wanted to know!